# is Kendo ui supports VS Community 2015

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik

Is the Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC i.e) Kendo UI will supports the VS Community 2015 Edition?

Tell me about the kendo VS extension also...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check out UI for ASP.NET MVC product overview page here: http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc

Also the demos for UI for ASP.NET MVC are available online here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc

VS Extension for UI for ASP.NET MVC is nothing but HTML helpers or what is called as Wrappers for Kendo UI. Since its MVC you dont do a drag & drop development. Instead you get helpers for most of the Kendo UI widgets.

for e.g. in Razor you will create a Kendo UI DatePicker like below:

@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("dob"))

Do check out the URLs i gave you above to get more information.

hope this helps.